# Widget with same content across several websites

Tags: plugins, xml

I'm managing a couple of websites from the same client. They have lots of partners and have a logo slider on the bottom of each page across 5 websites. 
The partners change from time to time and the content manager has to update the logos on 5 sites separately.

Maybe there's a way so that you can change the logos one time and the other sites change too.

I was thinking of a hosted xml file and images, and a widget on the site parses the xml and puts the content in a simple logo slider similar to this: https://wordpress.org/plugins/logo-slider/

Would that be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

for the idea of storing data on the provider webside, it's a good idea but I recommend to use JSON onstead of XML. it's a litte bit faster to parse and you will save a litte bit bandwith

on the provider side, you can use the WordPress AJAX helpers to make somethig like that :

```
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_logoData", function () {

    $data = array(
        "text" => "the new logo",
        "url" => "http://provider-server/wp-content/logo6.png";
    );

    echo json_encode($data);

    exit();
});
```

and on the client side (the 5 websites), you can do that to receive data :

```
$response = wp_remote_get("http://provider-server/wp-admin/adin-ajax.php?action=logoData");

$data = json_decode($response);

var_dump($data); // will show the array with the data
```